# Difference with and without www, 301 redirect with codeigniter and htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a domain that shows different pages if I leave out the *www*. Without the *www* the page freezes, so I want to redirect the *http://example.com* to *http://www.example.com*

My question is, how do I change the *htaccess* so it redirects to the www version?

Here is my **.htaccess**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Mr. Smith's rewrite should be fine, but if you're showing different pages entirely based on the www not being there then it sounds like a misconfiguration of the apache vhost.

Comment: I fully agree with you skrilled :)

Comment: It's showing the same page but without the www it freezes when you have chosen an option from a drop down list. Could it still be a misconfiguration of the apache vhost?

Comment: If we don't see your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend solved my problem by adding the following code underneath the existing code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now everything works perfectly! The complete .htaccess file now looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But keep in mind, making redirecting rule is just a compromise for your application, not solution for your page freezing problem.